# Search in all JSON fields with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

How could I query a JSON field to search in all fields of the JSON?

Table

```
id | JSON
--------------------------
 1 | {"name":"toto","age":25,"surname":"toto2"}
```

I'd like to query on every fields of the JSON, because I'm programming a global search function, and i need for example to return every row containing "toto" in its JSON.

I managed to do it in SqlServer 2016 with OPEN_JSON function.

Here is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM ObjectsTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([JSON]) as tbValues
WHERE tbValues.value like '%toto%'
```

I need to do the same thing in Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially the same in Postgres, but `cross apply` is `cross join lateral` in the SQL standard and in Postgres

```
select o.id, t.*
from objectstable o
  cross join lateral json_each_text(o.json) as t(k,val)
where t.val like '%toto%'
```